# Meaning of "public affairs" and "public interest"

Tags: meaning

The definition of *political* from OALD is:

> connected with the state, government or public affairs

Is the definition of *public* of public affairs definition 1 or 2 or neither?

> 1. of, relating to, or affecting all or most of the people of a country, state, etc.
> 2. connected with the government and the services it provides

From dictionary.com, *affairs* is defined as:

> matters of commercial or public interest or concern

Which of the following is the definition of *interest* of public interest?

> 1. the quality that something has when it attracts somebody's attention or makes them want to know more about it
> 2. a good result or an advantage for somebody/something

Comment: Great answers. since votes and answers are similar I'm going to accept coleopterist's according to submission time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of both these terms can vary depending on context. *Public affairs* might relate to government policy, company policy, or simply function as a catch-all term for a relationship with the public (through, for example, the media). So, both of your listed definitions could be applicable.

*Public interest*, again, could cover matters which are *of* interest to the public or are considered to be *beneficial* to the public. IOW, both of your listed definitions could again be applicable.

Comment: In other words: what's **in** the *public interest* is **of** the *public interest*.

Answer (score 1):

"*Public*" in "*public affairs*" would be your definition # 1:

```
of, relating to, or affecting all or most of the people of a country, state, etc.
```

Here's an example: To be the director of [public affairs](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/public%5B1%5D) means your work "involves events, activities, etc., that a company does for the public."

But if we take into account this other definition of "*public affairs*":

> [matters of general interest or concern, especially those dealing with
>   current social or political issues](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/public-affairs)

This definition will encompass/ include your definition #2:

```
connected with the government and the services it provides
```

---

On the other hand, "*interest*" in "*public interest*" could be both your definitions.

As the [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/public+interest) puts it more precisely:

**public interest**

n.

> 1. The **well-being** of the general public
> 2. The **attention** of the people with respect to events